# Publish an Azure Web App via Visual Studio for Mac

Tags: visual-studio, azure, asp.net-core, visual-studio-mac

I've created a sample asp.net core application using `Visual Studio for Mac` and trying to publish it to `Azure`. My wizard shows me nothing once opened and hangs at the `Querying subscriptions` step:

[image]

If I go to preferences -> account - I have a similar issue with the account wizard:

[image]

Comment: Try closing Visual Studio for Mac and deleting the `~/.ServiceHub` directory.  If that does not work you can try deleting both the `~/.ServiceHub` and the `~/.IdentityService` directory. Then start Visual Studio for Mac and log in again.

Comment: that helped, publish to Azure failed though with another error but it's a different story. Thanks!. Please post your answer as reply and I mark it as an asnwer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Currently there is a bug with the authentication in Visual Studio for Mac. It can sometimes be worked around by doing the following:

Close Visual Studio for Mac, delete the `~/.ServiceHub` directory, and restart Visual Studio for Mac.

If that does not work you can try deleting both the `~/.ServiceHub` and the `~/.IdentityService` directory. Then start Visual Studio for Mac and log in again.